# ASP.NET MVC Ajax example by Scott Allen isn't working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am watching videos of Scott Allen at pluralsight site, exactly I am talking about this [module](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building) :

**AJAX**:

So i created exactly the same example as shown at video, but it is not working, I have no idea why and spent an hour looking for this, here is my code:

```
At BoundleConfig.cs file:
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otf").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
            ));
```

At Web.config file in appSettings section I added:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

And here we go:

```
public ActionResult Review(string searchString)
    {

        var model = _repository.StartDs;


        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            model = model.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }




        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Review", model);
        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

Review.cshtml file :

```
@model IEnumerable<nauka.Models.StartData>
@using(Ajax.BeginForm(
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "get",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "girlsList"
                }))
{
    <input type="search"  name="searchString"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Znajdź" />

}
    @Html.Partial("_Review", Model)
```

_Review.cshtml file:

```
 @model IEnumerable<nauka.Models.StartData>




<div id="girlsList">
    <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Imię</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Wzrost</th>
            <th>Rozmiar</th>
            <th>Akcje</th>



        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
                <td>@item.Height</td>
                <td>@item.TitsSize</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Usuń", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })</td>
            </tr>



        }

    </table>

</div>
```

I checked it, this fragment at my action method :

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Review", model);
        }
```

never execute, which means that a request isn't recognized as an AjaxRequest, the question is why? I edited this line and pasted

```
return View("Index");
```

so it shloud redirect me to my Index site, but it didn't so i proved that AjaxRequest is not executed. I have no idea, what is missing here, I did exactly as at video shown.

Above my _Layout.cshtml file which is autmatically added to every view page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dodaj", "Add", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Przegladaj", "Review", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Filtruj", "FilterTest", "Home")</li>


                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you not hitting the code inside `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` then it means you making a normal redirect. Check that you scripts are being rendered correctly in the view (you have shown a bundle but have not shown where your include them in the view)

Comment: At the bottom of _Layout.cshtml file :   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/otf")

Comment: add all jquery refrences file to razor page ?

Comment: yeah, i added to them to _Layout.cshtml file, which is automatically added by _ViewStart.cshtml to every view page..

Answer (score 0):

Ough... solved!!

I didn't add a

**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**  library to my solution through NuGet package installer.
But when I added this before to BoudleConfig ( path
 "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",), why it didn't shout that this library isn't present at my project in Visual ??!
It made many complications..